# dynamic resource binding to list?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, resources

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="key_t"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox />
```

How do i bind window.resource dynamically to listbox ?

Comment: Please **[read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)** **[something](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)** before asking such basic questions.

Comment: Also don't tag every question with `visual-studio` while the question has absolutely nothing to do with the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for *dynamic* binding:

```xml
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource key_t}"></ListBox>
```

However, I don't see why you'd need *dynamic* binding in your example. Thus, I'd suggest to use *static* binding instead:

```xml
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource key_t}"></ListBox>
```

Comment: thank you very much, i was blind i guess, i though for a moment that there isn't such a thing for listbox.